# find a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

> Find $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n^2 = o(f(n))$ and $f(n) = o(n^{2+\varepsilon})$.

So I thought about the function $f(n) = \left\lfloor n^{2+\varepsilon} \right\rfloor$

I already was able to prove that $f(n) = o(n^{2+\varepsilon})$, but had some troubles with the other part.

I tried to use the fact that $$\forall x. x-1 \le \lfloor x \rfloor$$

I'd be glad for help (by the way, is that a sufficiently elegant function for the problem?)

Comment: The title is extraordinarily undescriptive.

Comment: I suspect you want $f(n)=o(n^{2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$, not just one.

Comment: Write $f(n) = n^2 g(n)$. Reduce the given problem to one about $g$.

Comment: Your approach fails for two reasons: **(1)** If $g(n) \geq 1$, then $g(n) = \Theta(\lfloor g(n) \rfloor)$, so taking the floor function doesn't affect the asymptotic behavior. **(2)** If you pick some $\epsilon_0$ and define $f(n) = n^{2 + \epsilon_0}$, then in the $\epsilon=\epsilon_0 / 2$ case, $f(n) = \omega(n^{2 + \epsilon})$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, right. It was a rookie mistake I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(n) = n^2\ln(n)$.

$\frac{n^2}{f(n)}
=\frac1{\ln(n)}
\to 0$
so
$n^2 = o(f(n))$.

$\frac{f(n))}{n^{2+\epsilon}}
=\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{\epsilon}}
\to 0
$
since
$\ln(n) = o(n^{\epsilon})$
for any $\epsilon > 0$
so
$f(n)
= o(n^{2+\epsilon})
$
for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Note:
To show
$\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{\epsilon}}
\to 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{\epsilon}}
&=\frac1{\epsilon}\frac{\epsilon\ln(n)}{n^{\epsilon}}\\
&=\frac1{\epsilon}\frac{ln(n^{\epsilon})}{n^{\epsilon}}\\
&\to 0
\end{array}
$

since
$\frac{\ln(n)}{n}
\to 0
$.

Comment: Thanks. More precisely, $f(n) = \lfloor n^2 \ln n \rfloor$, right? since $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: Floor or ceiling, doesn't matter if the function is unbounded  when working with big oh stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>1$: Let $g(n)=1/\sqrt {\log n}$ .

Let $f(n)=$Floor$(n^{2+g(n)}).$

Then $f(n)n^{-2}\geq$  $(n^{2+g(n)}-1)n^{-2}=$ $n^{g(n)}-n^{-2}=$ $(e^{\log n})^{g(n)}-n^{-2}=$ $e^{\sqrt {\log n}}-n^{-2}$, which $\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$

And for any fixed $\epsilon >0$ we have $n^{2+\epsilon}f(n)^{-1}\geq$ $n^{2+\epsilon}n^{-2-g(n)}=$ $n^{\epsilon-1/\sqrt {\log n}}$, which $\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$

Remark: Floor$(n^{2+\epsilon})$ is NOT $o(n^{2+\epsilon})$ as $n\to \infty.$ when  $\epsilon >0.$

Because $1\geq$ Floor$(n^{2+\epsilon})n^{-2-\epsilon}\geq 1-n^{-2-\epsilon},$ which $\to 1$ as $n\to \infty.$